# Failed import of Mapbox features, trying to make a Geocoding Autocomplete query

Tags: android, import, geocoding, mapbox

Let me explain my issue.
I am really newbie in terms of Mapbox handling, but however im getting really good experiences with it. Today, I got an issue which I couldn't solve for hours and hours, which is related to some imports I fail to get from mapbox android services library.

I am compiling the following services in my build.gradle file:

```
compile('com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-sdk:5.0.1@aar') {
    transitive=true
}
compile ('com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-geocoder:1.0.+@aar'){
    transitive=true
}
compile ('com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-services:2.0.0-beta.1@aar'){
    transitive=true
}
```

And everything works fine with the map, it shows me the map, I can add markers, modify parameters, and more stuff. My problem is, that when I try to make a geocoding automatic-fill query, the following lines in the import section are marked in grey and for no apparent reason, the imports aren't being done correctly.

```
import com.mapbox.services.android.geocoder.ui.GeocoderAutoCompleteView;
import com.mapbox.services.geocoding.v5.GeocodingCriteria;
import com.mapbox.services.geocoding.v5.models.CarmenFeature;
```

So, in the call into the java class, i'm getting a few errors related to lack of references.

```
// Set up autocomplete widget
GeocoderAutoCompleteView autocomplete = (GeocoderAutoCompleteView) findViewById(R.id.query);
autocomplete.setAccessToken(MapboxAccountManager.getInstance().getAccessToken());
autocomplete.setType(GeocodingCriteria.TYPE_POI);
autocomplete.setOnFeatureListener(new GeocoderAutoCompleteView.OnFeatureListener() {
    @Override
    public void OnFeatureClick(CarmenFeature feature) {
        Position position = feature.asPosition();
        updateMap(position.getLatitude(), position.getLongitude());
    }
});
```

Any idea? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Were you able to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the new documentation for the [geocoding widget](https://www.mapbox.com/android-docs/mapbox-services/2.0.0/geocoder/#android-widgets) along with the getting started guide. This should be your XML file:

```
<com.mapbox.services.android.ui.geocoder.GeocoderAutoCompleteView
```

android:id="@+id/autoCompleteWidget"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:hint="Search Location"
  android:maxLines="1"/>

Also you should upgrade to not using the beta. Stable 2.0.0 has been released.